# Java: get specific table from my sql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I have a code in which i can get all my tables, but how i can get my table i specify. Here is my code :

```
private void initComponents() {            
  System.out.println("trying to connect");
  try{
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
     System.out.println("Connected");  
  } catch(SQLException e){
     System.err.print(e);
  }           
  jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
  jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
  jTextField1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            jTextField1.setText("");
        }
  });
  jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
  jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {                            
            System.out.println("paspausta");
            String molecule = jTextField1.getText();
            try{
               DatabaseMetaData metadata;
               metadata = conn.getMetaData();

               String[] types = {"TABLE"};
               ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", types);

               while (resultSet.next()) {
                   String tableName = resultSet.getString(3); 
                   System.out.println("Table : " + tableName ); 
               }
            } catch (SQLException e) { 
               System.out.println("Could not get database metadata " + e.getMessage());
            }
      }  

   });
```

Here i have frame. In that frame there is text field and a button. My idea is to write table name in text field and after pressing a button get all info about that exact table i wrote in a text field. But so far i was able to make to get all tables from my database and i dont know how to get one table i specify.

Comment: Personally, I just load all the tables and store the meta data, maybe using a `Map` to make it easier to lookup later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
```

To:

```
ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, molecule, types);
```